# Get value from dropdown and pass it to another function (JS)

Tags: javascript, forms

can you tell me what's wrong with my code?

I've got this dropdown list:

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" onchange="getSelectedValue();">  
<option value="1">Text 1</option>  
<option value="2">Text 2</option>
```

And the following script:

```
function getSelectedValue() {  
var index = document.getElementById('mySelect').selectedIndex;  
var index = document.getElementById('mySelect').value;  
return index;    
}  
function passValue(x){
var a = x;
alert(a);
}    
passValue(getSelectedValue());
```

The getSelectedValue function works fine, but when I try to pass the value it returns to the passValue function nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I copied your code into a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/wqq4pmte/ and it alerts the value of the selected item in your select element.  What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: This is really strange, I tried it in JS Bin and nothing would happen. The only difference was that I did not split it between the HTML and JS windows but embeded the JS code in the HTML. I'll check it out in Webstorm when I get home, thanks!

Comment: I have to double-post for visibility:  In your JS fiddle the code only alerts the first selected item, why's that?

Comment: It's showing the first value because both functions are being called when the page is loaded, and therefore the first value is alerted.  I'm guessing you want to alert the value when the select element is changed?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I would like the code to do:)

Comment: I would suggest using the jquery to make this easy.  Here is the fiddle updated with jquery included,  http://jsfiddle.net/wqq4pmte/2/

Comment: It works fine now, thank you, I really appreciate your help; however, I have currently no knowledge of jquery (started learning JS from scratch a couple of weeks ago) and I really try to always understand the way the code works before I use it. Wouldn't it be a problem for you to provide me with a pure JS code?

Comment: @marty I just edited the post--have you seen this new feature? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/element.onchange.html.

Comment: @user2314737 please don't duplicate code when you are snippetting... should i roll back the edit..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event listener and call `passValue` function as follows:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');

select.addEventListener("change",function() {
  passValue(this.value);
});

function passValue(x) {
  var a = x;
  console.log(a);
}
```

```html
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" >
  <option value="1">Text 1</option>
  <option value="2">Text 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getSelectedValue() {  
var index = document.getElementById('mySelect').selectedIndex;  
var index = document.getElementById('mySelect').value;  
return index;    
}  
function passValue(x){
var a = x();
alert(a);
}

jQuery('#mySelect').change(function(){
    passValue(getSelectedValue)
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm not acquainted with jquery yet, but I'll have a look at it.